# How to concatenate two String beans in a configuration file in Spring 2.5

Tags: java, spring

I know that Spring 3.0 and up has EL, but in this case the project is using Spring 2.5 , example:

```
<bean id="dir" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="c:/work/"
</bean>

<bean id="file" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="file.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="path" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value=**dir +  file**/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<bean id="dir" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="c:/work/"
</bean>

<bean id="file" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="file.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="path" factory-bean="dir" factory-method="concat">
    <constructor-arg ref="file"/>
</bean>
```

Notice the usage of [`String.concat(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String)) method as `factory-method`.

But XML isn't really the best place for stuff like this, what about Java `@Configuration`?

```
@Configuration
public class Cfg {
    @Bean
    public String dir() {
        return "c:/work/";
    }

    @Bean
    public String file() {
        return "file.properties";
    }

    @Bean
    public String path() {
        return dir() + file();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring is not the place to store application logic like this.

If you need that, add a `getPath()` method that does something like:

```
public String getPath() {
    if(path == null) {
        path = getDir() + getPath();
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use Spring-EL?
Take a look at this [LINK](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

With Spring-EL you can do something like the following:

```
<bean id="dir" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="path" value="c:/work/" />
</bean>
<bean id="file" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="fileName" value="file.properties" />
</bean>
<bean id="path" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{dir.path}#{file.fileName}"/>
</bean>
```

This is available since Spring 3.0.

Comment: you can try to do sth like this:

<bean id="dir" class="java.lang.String">
 <property name="path" value="c:/work/" />
</bean>

<bean id="file" class="java.lang.String">
 <property name="fileName" value="file.properties" />
</bean>

<bean id="path" class="java.lang.String">
    <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{dir.path}#{file.fileName}"/>
</bean>

Comment: Spring-El is not  useful in this case , because it is available since Spring 3.0, I am using Spring 2.5, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can use ref instead of value. I.e.

```
<bean id="path" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg ref="file"/>
</bean>
```