# Spring property injection and property initialization order

Tags: java, spring, jvm, spring-bean

```
class A {

private String field1="123";

private String field2="prefix"+field1;

getter&setter;
}
```

filed1 is injected by one value("abc") defined in property file.
In some cases, value of field2 is always "prefix123" rather than "prefixabc".

Does property injection and initialization have order?

Comment: You may perform the concatenation directly inside the configuration, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566084/how-to-concatenate-two-string-beans-in-a-configuration-file-in-spring-2-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261372/concatenate-strings-within-a-spring-xml-configuration-file . This will ensure that the field1 String bean is initialized before it gets concatenated .

Answer (score 0):

It could be safer to initialize field two inside a postconstruct method:

```
@PostConstruct
void initFieldTwo(){
  field2="prefix"+field1;
}
```

That way you know it will happen after field 1 has been initialized.